# Photo markup software for old photos

Tags: photography, catalog

I would like markup people on old photos. Just draw rectangles and specify who is it. May be also with database.

The very important requirement is using open and eternal standards. Since it is old historical photos, I cant rely on solution, which may disappear or unpredictable evolve in future versions. I need markup survive many years. So, no ACDSee and no Picasa please.

Comment: No solution is "eternal", not even an indelible marker on the original photos ;) Apple's Photos can do this though I'm not sure if it has a Windows-accessible equivalent [& when people don't specify an OS, it's usually because they think everybody uses Windows].

Comment: No, this is because I don't need OS-specific solution. OS can disappear.

Comment: No solution is eternal. Whichever you use you will subsequently need to monitor, maintain & update it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and ended up with

- Piwigo.org 11 Photo gallery hosted on a private web server
- Plugin https://github.com/cccraig/MugShot (I had to use the master branch which is mostly compatible with Piwigo 11) - this let's you draw rectangles and tag persons

In addition to your requirement I wanted to be able to share and collaboratively tag the data.

Concerning eternal standards / backup:

- The plugin stores the face data the MySQL Database table face_tag_positions  - you can export this using PHPMyAdmin / Adminer manually on a regular basis
- You might also have to export the table `piwigo_tags` and `piwigo_images`

By archiving this data you might be able to reconstruct the tagging information even without constantly updating the Piwigo server.

With a bit of work it should also be possible to export this data to static HTML Files (with Imagemaps) which probably is a good format for archival. But then you loose the comfort of editing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing nothing is truly eternal.
Your going to time to create a virtual machine so you can isolate all requirements into a single container.

Then have multiple copies.

Your going to have to multiple archived copies of all relevant software in multiple locations.

As long as you keep your virtual machine software up to date it should last a long time.  In the long long term major changes to the structure of virtual machine software may change enough some kind of migration process is necessary.